# Command \braket error

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I was trying to write this formula:

```
$\braket{A} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$
```

but this error pops out

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \braket
l.254 $\braket
{A} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: You have not shown your code but presumably you have not defined `\braket` which is not a standard command, what do you want it to do?

Comment: I just need to create this math formula: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVvgK9aqru2mCJ0YJk6u98eeUJi?e=YbOgKA
I'm using \amsmath

Comment: That is not called bracket, `\langle A \rangle`

Comment: Thanks Is working now